# Kafka error while running command to start zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have kafka installed at following location

> C:\Users\username\work\data\kafkadirectory\kafka\apache-kafka\kafka

Now, when I run following command at above location:

> path/to/zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties

I get error:

> The input line is too long.
>
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

As can be seen, directory names don't include version(google search tells to get rid of version in directory names).

Still I face the issue.

Comment: Try reducing folder hierarchy, put Kafka dist to C or D drive

Answer (score 0):

Try the below-mentioned steps

1. Better to move the folder to short path 'C:\kafka\' (Reducing folder hierarchy)
2. Restart the command prompt to reset the classpath variable
3. Use PowerShell which have longer support to the classpath